# Why my marker is not pointed to my current location

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, ionic3, ionic-native

i'm able to get `GoogleMap` on my `Android` device , the problem is it is not pointing to my `current` `location`.

I have installed these 2 packages:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE" 

$ npm install --save @ionic-native/google-maps
```

**below is how my google map looks on my android device**

[image]

**below is my code:**

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad GoogleMapTestPage');
    this.loadMap();
  }


ngAfterViewInit() {
 //this.loadMap();         
}

loadMap() {

 // create a new map by passing HTMLElement
 let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');

 let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element);

 // listen to MAP_READY event
 // You must wait for this event to fire before adding something to the map or modifying it in anyway
 map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(
   () => {
     console.log('Map is ready!');
     // Now you can add elements to the map like the marker
   }
 );

 // create LatLng object
 let ionic: LatLng = new LatLng(43.0741904,-89.3809802);  

 // create CameraPosition 
 let position: any = {
   target: ionic,
   zoom: 18,
   tilt: 30
 };

 // move the map's camera to position
 map.moveCamera(position);

 // create new marker
 let markerOptions: MarkerOptions = {
   position: ionic,
   title: 'Ionic'
 };

 const marker:any = map.addMarker(markerOptions)
   .then((marker: Marker) => {
      marker.showInfoWindow();
    });
 }
```

**my html code**

```
 <ion-content>    
      <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>  
</ion-content>
```

**My Question:**

**how to point to my `current location` in the above code!!**

please help me as I am new to ionic 3, just I wanted to point to users current

location on google !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make changes on the map like adding marker *once it is ready*. So move the marker setting code to `map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)`.

```
 let ionic: LatLng = new LatLng(43.0741904,-89.3809802);  

 // create CameraPosition 
 let position: any = {
   target: ionic,
   zoom: 18,
   tilt: 30
 };

 map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(
   () => {
     console.log('Map is ready!');
     // Now you can add elements to the map like the marker
      map.moveCamera(position);

     // create new marker
    let markerOptions: MarkerOptions = {
        position: ionic,
        title: 'Ionic'
    };

    const marker:any = map.addMarker(markerOptions)
        .then((marker: Marker) => {
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        });
    }  
   }
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and declare variable `map:GoogleMap;` before constructor after class. So you can reuse your map without render map more and more .Because every single load page your google map api quota is increasing .

My suggestion :
Put loading map on provider

```js
this.map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(()=>{
      console.log("Map ready");
      this.map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
      this.map.getMyLocation({enableHighAccuracy:true}).then(pos=>{
        this.map.setCameraTarget(pos.latLng);
        this.map.animateCamera({
          target:pos.latLng
        });

        this.map.addMarker({
            title: 'You',
            icon: 'pin'
            animation: 'DROP',
            position: pos.latLng
        }).then((marker)=>{
          this.userMarker = marker;
            marker.setPosition(pos.latLng);

          });
        });
      });
```

Comment: Reza, the cordova-plugin-googlemaps (@ionic-native/google-maps) uses native Google Maps API, not JavaScript API. Google does not set quota for native Google Maps APIs.

Comment: @wf9a5m75 wow ! that's great when i know we are not charged by using google maps quota :D

Answer (score 0):

For add marker you have to add marker on your map object with lat&lng and title.
have look:

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(22.7253, 75.8655)).title("Title"));
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: where to add this code? will it give current position in google map.

Comment: for current location you have to get lat&lng from geolocation and set it to above code. for adding above line you created map object in your code.

Comment: for more info have look this http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.in/2012/12/add-informationobject-to-marker-in.html

Answer (score -1):

Firstly make sure your API Key is valid and add this into your manifest ``
Then use add map.setMyLocationEnabled(true) inside the **onMapReady(GoogleMap map)** method. like this

@Override

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap gMap) {
   mGoogleMap = gMap;
   mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   buildGoogleApiClient();
   mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}
```

Comment: I assume this is native android? OP has tagged ionic which is hybrid...